# Sharepoint 2013 AverageRatingFieldControl Rating not supported

Tags: social

I've been trying to get the Rating control working inside a visual web part with no success. I've tried every example I could find online with the same result showing "Rating not supported". I assume everything is setup correctly and I can see and Rate each list item on the View itself. I have the list item and try to bind it to the control. Here is my VWP code:

```
<SharePointPortalControls:AverageRatingFieldControl  ID="PageRatingControl" FieldName="AverageRating" runat="server" />

SPContext _itemContext = SPContext.GetContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, newsItem.ID, newsItem.ParentList.ID, newsItem.ListItems.List.ParentWeb);
PageRatingControl.FieldName = "AverageRating";
PageRatingControl.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
PageRatingControl.ItemContext = _itemContext;
```

I tried changing the Field name, controlMode, Context, List Item used. Why can I perform ratings on the list item directly but not through this control? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't activate Ratings on the Page library itself, only on my 'News' custom list. Even though you are targeting a specific list item, the page in which is resides need to have Ratings activated as well. FTW

Check out this detailed blog posting for more details:

http://sp77.blogspot.ca/2013/07/rating-webpart-using.html#.U1kw9PldV8E

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have registered the **Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal**  assembly in your ascx page.If not add it as below:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointPortalControls"
    Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

If above tag is registered and is still giving the error, alternatively you can also try to create the `AverageRatingFieldControl` control from the code behind and add that control to any panel/div.

```
<asp:Panel ID="ratingPnl" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

            SPContext _itemContext = SPContext.GetContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, newsItem.ID, newsItem.ParentList.ID, newsItem.ListItems.List.ParentWeb);
            AverageRatingFieldControl PageRatingControl = new AverageRatingFieldControl();
            PageRatingControl.ID = "PageRatingControl";
            PageRatingControl.ListId = newsItem.ID;
            PageRatingControl.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
            PageRatingControl.FieldName = "AverageRating";
            PageRatingControl.ItemContext = _itemContext;
            ratingPnl.Controls.Add(PageRatingControl);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution wouldn't compile if I didn't have that server tag registered. And I already tried creation from code behind with the same result.